# Property declared in my class isn't recognized when attempting to use it inside a function?

Tags: swift, properties, declaration

I've checked for the misspelling of the property, that's definitely not the case. I'm trying to use the property `mySong` that I declared in my class inside the `parseSongs()` function.

That function isn't inside the class but it's in the same file. And the target membership of that class is set to the project name as are the other files as well.

I'm very confused why the compiler isn't recognizing the name of my property in the `parseSongs()`?

I can declare the property outside of the class but I should be able to use it even if it's declared inside the class.

```
import UIKit

class SongsTableViewController: UITableViewController {

//A property that is an array of type 'Song'
var mySong = [Song]()

private let cache = NSCache()

private func fetchMyData(){

    let myUrl = NSURL(string: "http://itunes.apple.com/search?term=beatles&country=us")!
    let mySession = NSURLSession.sharedSession()

    //The work to be queued initiates
    let myTask = mySession.dataTaskWithURL(myUrl){
    //This closure right here is the Completion Handler

        data, response, error in
        if error != nil{
            //Handle error

        }else{

            let myHttpResponse = response as! NSHTTPURLResponse
            switch myHttpResponse.statusCode {
            case 200..<300:
                print("OK")
                print("data: \(data)")
            default: print("request failed: \(myHttpResponse.statusCode)")

            }
        }
    }
    myTask.resume()
 }

}

func parseJson(myData data: NSData){

do{

    let json: AnyObject? = try NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(data, options: [])
    if let unwrappedJson: AnyObject = json{

        parseSongs(unwrappedJson)
    }
}catch{

 }
}


 func parseSongs(json1: AnyObject){
     mySong = []

    //Optional Binding
    if let array = json1["results"] as? [[String:AnyObject]]{
        //For-In loop
        for songDictionary in array{

            if let title = songDictionary["trackName"] as? NSString{

                if let artist = songDictionary["artistName"] as? NSString{

                    if let albumName = songDictionary ["collectionName"] as? NSString{

                        if let artWorkUrl = songDictionary["artWorkUrl100"] as? NSString {
                            let song = Song(artist: (artist as String), title: (title as String), albumName: (albumName as String), artWorkUrl: (artWorkUrl as String))

                            mySong.append(song)
                        }
                    }

                }
            }
        }

        dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue()){
            self.tableView.reloadData()
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To use the property outside which declared inside a class you have to follow this

```
 SongsTableViewController().theProperty
```

If you declare it outside class then you can access it in function of outside class

Comment: I see, but its not a class property its an instance property, so shouldn't I be able to use it without having to access it through dot syntax?

Comment: As you say its an instance property so till i know no other way. :)

Comment: I just edited the question and included which property it was. The author of the book that I took this example out of, did `mySong = []` he did not do `SongsTableViewController().mySong`?